# Javascript- can I have a display value and send null in the backend

Tags: javascript

I am novice when it comes to Javascript.
We are trying to change an existing field on a page. Its a text field but is a float in the backend. We want to change it slightly so the user can enter NA in the field but we should send null to the backend when the action class is called. This is just to ensure none of the existing validations fail.
I tried the following , but the display value changes to null as well.

```
if(temp === 'N' || temp==='NA'){
    var tst=document.getElementById("statusPercent");
    tst.value=null;
}
```

Comment: You should do this kind of operations in the backend. Never trust user input.

Comment: You cannot do that in a straightforward way. However, you can capture the submit event and create your own form and submit that instead.

Answer (score 0):

it is because your `tst` variable is your object from your input with the id "statusPercent".

I don't know how you send your data to your backend, but if you use AJAX, you just need to use another variable to store your `tst` value and send this value (which can be either the true value or NA)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Data is sent back as POJO. <s:textfield name="client.StatusPercent" cssClass="frmTxtBox" onblur="extractNumber(this,'2',false);" onkeyup="extractNumber(this,'2',false);"/> 
       &nbsp;<span class="field_label_left">%</span></td> .The Extract Number fn checks to see if the user entered any numbers or text, this is where I am setting the value to null